# Dash app - update database from another location (PC)

Tags: flask, heroku, web-applications, dashboard, plotly-dash

Basically I am struggling to understand how a heroku-deployed web app can be interacted with from another PC. I just finished my first web app and am on the final step of deploying it using heroku git. The script reads the data as an .csv file using pandas and then carries on with all of the analysis to be displaed on the app.

However, I developed this app for a person wants to be able to periodically upgrade the said .csv file to visualise various datasets of the same type (i.e. the dataset will not be the same always and I am not the one who will be updating the dataset, it will be someone else from a different computer). The said person most likely will not have Anaconda installed.

I'm super inexperienced in this area and I couldn't find online anything about this specific case, any clarification/advice/pointers to learning resources will be greatly appreciated. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: what kind of database you are using?

Comment: It will be an .xls file, I read the file into a Pandas dataframe using pd.read_csv. Or did you mean something else? :)